# If Noah's Flood was a historical global flood then how is the evidence that Egypt was founded before the Flood explained?

Tags: history, genesis, flood-of-noah, young-earth-creation

The common consensus is that Noah's flood occurred around the 2200-2300 BCE. If this is so, then how could Egypt have been founded by Narmer in 3100 BCE? Is Mizraim the founder of Egypt? Or is Mizraim simply a descendant of Noah who inhabited alongside the earlier peoples?

This question is directed at people who believe that Noah's Flood was a historical global event, including Young Earth Creationists.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. I've edited the question to be more like one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If is not inline with what you were trying to ask in the first place then you may [edit] it back.

Comment: "Literalist" is always an unhelpful word. The issue is not about figurativeness or literalness of passages, but whether they are believed to be historical or not. Historicist or [Biblical Maximalist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historicity_of_the_Bible#Maximalist_.E2.80.93_Minimalist_dichotomy) are much better terms to use. I say this because I don't think there's any exegetical support to say that Genesis figuratively describes a historical local flood, so instead people say that it tells of a mythical global flood (potentially inspired by a local flood).

Comment: @Jas3.1 Yeah this is a subset of that question, but I think it would be good to keep this one open because the specific details that will come from this one wouldn't be produced for the other.

Comment: This is a subset of the larger question, but the detail and the scope is better.  This may be the case of a great answer saving a good question.

Answer (score 8):

Like Young Earth Creationists do with most things, they believe that the conventional dating systems are wrong.

In the case of Egypt this involves saying that what are normally thought to be sequential dynasties are actually concurrent dynasties. The most extreme accounts propose that the First and Second Intermediate Periods are actually one period, a time of chaos caused by the Exodus. Some identify the Hyksos with the Amelekites who the Israelites fought just after the Exodus (chapter 17). Note that while almost all YECs would say the chronologies need revising, there are many proposed alternatives, and specific theories like the following image are controversial.

[image: A diagram showing overlapping dynasties]

Here's a long article from Creation.com: [Egyptian chronology and the Bible—framing the issues](http://creation.com/egypt-chronology)