# How do we explain the flood happening on 2348 BC with Pyramid and Chinese that's been around long before that?

Tags: flood-of-noah

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37222/are-there-continuous-lines-of-cultural-records-throughout-the-period-of-the-bibl

According to calculations, the flood must have happened on 2348 BC more or less.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ussher_chronology

The problem is, I bet many chinese, Indians, and egyptian will protests.

They've been around in their place far longer than 2348 BC.

The Pyramid of Giza is 2589 BC

Comment: Duplicate of [If Noah's Flood was a historical global flood then how is the evidence that Egypt was founded before the Flood explained?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35323/6071) / [How do Young Earth Creationists account for civilisations with histories going back five thousand years or more?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7728/6071)